# Custom Android emulator (ranchu) build for AOSP 6

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, qemu

I need to build a custom version of the Android emulator and started with rebuilding the emulator without any changes for AOSP 6.0.1 R62.

To my surprise the emulator source code isn't included with AOSP any more. The emulators appear prebuilt in AOSP repository. After some research I managed to build the qemu (ranchu) itself:

1. I downloaded the qemu sources:

   ```
   git clone -b qemu-android-2.2.0 \
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu-android
   ```
2. I downloaded the Android build scripts for qemu that are in a different repository:

   ```
   git clone https://qemu-android.googlesource.com/qemu-ranchu
   ```
3. I ran `qemu-ranchu/scripts/rebuild.sh`

The script built qemu and generated a binary `qemu-system-aarch64` in `qemu-ranchu/binaries/linux-x86_64/`. In AOSP there is a file with the same name in `$aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/` but this not the file that the end user would execute. An Android developer would run the executable called `emulator` in `$aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/`, which apparently is some kind of a wrapper around the bare qemu binary.

So the actual questions are:

1. Is there any documentation on ranchu build and all it involves? I cannot find any :(
2. Do the `emulator*` executables contain inside them the qemu or do they execute an external qemu binary?
3. If I overwrite the qemu binaries in `aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/` with my custom binaries, would running `emulator` actually invoke my custom qemu?
4. Can I bypass `emulator` and run my `qemu-system-aarch64` directly to boot an AOSP image? Or is it insane to try to configure it?
5. Where are the sources of all the `emulator*` binaries?

Answer (score 0):

The "ranchu" model was the next iteration of the "goldfish" platform. It was a light weight tweak of the "virt" board with some VirtIO devices (block, network, console) as well as a custom para-virtualised "pipe" device. This allowed the user space of the guest to communicate with the host which is used both for features like communicating with adb on the host as well as a pass-through interface for accelerated OpenGL commands.

The "emulator" command is as you correctly surmise a wrapper around the main (heavily forked) QEMU binary. It provided for a a glue between QEMU itself and the skinned display of the emulated phone. Aside from the adb, console and GL it also does some tracing and memory monitoring.

There is now a more modern emulator called cuttlefish which does away with some of the more NIH google additions and uses VirtIO for a more standardised device model. The emulator itself is based on CrosVM and designed to be runnable under KVM which makes it more suitable for at-scale testing in the cloud.

To summarise the answers to your questions:

1. The only real documentation is in the source code
2. emulator executes an external forked version of QEMU
3. maybe, I seem to recall the QEMU it builds is called qemu-android
4. a plain QEMU build is unlikely to work although you might get a CLI only version of Android working with enough effort
5. the code is in the AOSP tree

My (very old) notes are as follows:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b emu-master-dev
cd ${REPO_ROOT}external/qemu
./android-configure.sh --no-strip --debug
make -j4

#The actual "QEMU2" emulator will be in ../qemu-android but the qemu
#directory includes all the wrapper programs you need. The emulator
##configure script overrides and replaces the upstream configure script
#and ensures it is properly linked in with the OpenGL wrappers.

export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/home/alex/lsrc/qemu/android/hackbox.generic
./objs/emulator -verbose -show-kernel -logcat '*:s' -selinux permissive -kernel ~/lsrc/qemu/linux.git/arch/arm/boot/zImage -sysdir /home/alex/lsrc/qemu/android/hackbox.generic -data userdata.img -ranchu -memory 2548 -qemu -d unimp,guest_errors
```